# TIKTok TypeError in you-get

Tags: python

My command:

```
you-get https://www.tiktok.com/@mks.vision/video/7010448924213398789
you-get -x 127.0.0.1:PorxyPORT https://www.tiktok.com/@mks.vision/video/7010448924213398789
you-get -di https://www.tiktok.com/@mks.vision/video/7010448924213398789
```

No matter how I try all commands above, the following error always appears.
Error ouput with --debug option:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "T:\IntalledSofeware\PY36\Scripts\you-get.exe_main.py", line 9, in
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\site-packages\you_get_main.py", line 92, in main
main(**kwargs)
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\site-packages\you_get\common.py", line 1831, in main
script_main(any_download, any_download_playlist, **kwargs)
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\site-packages\you_get\common.py", line 1719, in script_main
**extra
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\site-packages\you_get\common.py", line 1345, in download_main
download(url, **kwargs)
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\site-packages\you_get\common.py", line 1822, in any_download
m.download(url, **kwargs)
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\site-packages\you_get\extractors\tiktok.py", line 14, in tiktok_download
info = json.loads(data)
File "t:\intalledsofeware\py36\lib\json_init_.py", line 348, in loads
'not {!r}'.format(s.class.name))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0):

works perfectly by me, maybe you are getting blocked,
when you posted the proxy, did you use an actual proxy?

```
C:\Users\flaxon>you-get https://www.tiktok.com/@mks.vision/video/7010448924213398789
Site:       TikTok.com
Title:      Mks [7010448924213398789]
Type:       MPEG-4 video (video/mp4)
Size:       3.13 MiB (3276993 Bytes)

Downloading Mks (7010448924213398789).mp4 ...
 100% (  3.1/  3.1MB) ├████████████████████████████████████████┤[1/1]   10 MB/s
```